# Binding text at a textblock is not working

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, catel

Am using framework catel, update the value in the timer send an event to the fact that the content is updated, but no changes occur. The data in the listbox are updated successfully. What's the problem?
XAML:

```
<TextBlock Margin="2,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding NowPlayingTime}" />
```

C#:

```
void _dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AboveTime = string.Format("{0:hh:mm:ss}", TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(_controlPlayer.NaturalDurationTimeSpan));
    NowPlayingTime = string.Format("{0:hh:mm:ss}", TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(_controlPlayer.NowPlayingPosition));
}
public string NowPlayingTime
{
    get { return _nowPlayingTime; }
    private set
    {
        _nowPlayingTime = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(() => NowPlayingTime);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you set some initial value to NowPlayingTime, is it displaying on TextBlock?

Comment: No, this text is not updated even if I send static text.

Comment: that means it is a binding error. can you check in your output window for any binding errors

Comment: I've always used OnPropertyChanged which takes the property name as a string. Could you include the implemntation of RaisePropertyChanged you're using? But then again, if the data in the listbox gets updated, then RaisePropertyChanged works fine.

Comment: Maybe the lambda expression gives the value in _nowPlayingTime to RaisePropertyChanged instead of the name of NowPlayingTime? So RaisePropertyChanged doesn't know what to update. Does RaisePropertyChanged("NowPlayingTime") work?

Comment: @Birdy if you found an answer I would recommend either updating your question with the answer or posting an answer separately with that code so future readers can see it (comments can get hidden)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution to the problem, if you use this code, everything is updated and working successfully.

```
private void _dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AboveTime = string.Format("{0:hh\\:mm\\:ss}", _controlPlayer.NaturalDurationTimeSpan);
    NowPlayingTime = string.Format("{0:hh\\:mm\\:ss}", _controlPlayer.NowPlayingPositionTimeSpan);
}
```